If God was real would there be physical evidence of him?
A theist claims that they have faith  in the truth of God despite any evidence to support and validate that faith.
An atheist does not share that faith in God because to validate truth, you need evidence of that truth?
If God exists would there be evidence of God to confirm the faith in that truth?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


If God was real would there be physical evidence of him?

This will depend on one's posited conception of God. Most (all?) religious beliefs in God are consistent with there being no physical evidence of that God.
